# Swift Sending Boolean Values in Alamofire Params

Tags: ios, parameters, swift3, alamofire, boolean-operations

In my app I need to send Boolean values inside alamofire params. Here is the code

```
var SearchParams = [String:Any]()
SearchParams["id"] = "125"
SearchParams["my_case"] = false
```

But in server end boolean value received as String. I have tried in multiple ways like

```
var SearchParams: [String:Anyobject]?
SrearchParams = ["id":"125","my_case": false]


var SearchParams = [String:AnyObject]()
SearchParams["id"] = "125" as AnyObject
SearchParams["my_case"] = false as AnyObject
```

But It Wont Works.

Comment: Try sending 0 or 1 for Boolean purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code Here:

```
var SearchParams = [String:Any]()
SearchParams["id"] = "\(self.SelectedId)"
SearchParams["my_case"] = false as Bool
let fileUrl = Foundation.URL(string: baseurl)
var request = URLRequest(url: fileUrl!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = ["FirmUserId": "\(self.FirmUserId)", "Authorization": "Token token=\(self.AuthToken)","UserId":"\(self.UserId)"]
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: SearchParams, options: .prettyPrinted)
Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { response in
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSNumber` class for passing boolean value. Like following code

```
SearchParams["my_case"] = NSNumber(value: false)
```

This will help you

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
var SearchParams= ["id":"123","iSActive": false] as [String : Any]
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me

```
var SearchParams= ["id":"123","iSActive": false] as [String : Any]
```